# Debug Flutter app on physical android on a Macbook

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have an app that I want to debug on a physical Galaxy 21 Ultra.
I'm working on M1 Macbook Pro(I don't know if that's the problem).
Anyway , the app is running on the simulator (iOS and Android).
The laptop and IDE recognize my phone but when I hit the debug button and keep looping on `building gradle` in vsCode , then leaves the debug mode and nothing happend.
PS: I used the same phone on my Windows machine and it's working properly.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hey could you open your terminal inside the `android` folder of your project and run `./gradlew assembleDebug ` to see which exactly is the output of gradle?

Comment: hi, were you able to solve , if yes please kindly tell us how you solve it. i'm in the same position now. thanks